# How does Windows decide which network adapter to use when there are two or more adapters?

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, windows-server

I am using VirtualBox, with an adapter connected to the internal network, and another connected to the internet through NAT. When I try to access a resource, will it send out the request through both adapters? Or is there something built into Windows that can tell whether an IP address is on the local network, and avoid sending to both adapters?

Answer (score 0):

In any TCP/IP system, there is a route table which indicates where a packet should go depending of its destination address. On Windows, the command `route print` shows the route table.

You will typically find a default route (0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0) given by the DHCP server, the LAN(s) directly connected to the PC and dome other routes.